# In RxJS, Why Check rxSubscriberSymbol in toSubscriber?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have read through parts of the [ReactiveX codebase](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) several times, and still cannot wrap my head around exactly what is going on [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/06f1a25123997e0419a421aa949e8969bc5daeb1/src/internal/util/toSubscriber.ts#L11-L19), in `toSubscribe.ts`:

```
if (nextOrObserver) {
  if (nextOrObserver instanceof Subscriber) {
    return (<Subscriber<T>> nextOrObserver);
  }

  if (nextOrObserver[rxSubscriberSymbol]) {
    return nextOrObserver[rxSubscriberSymbol]();
  }
}
```

**What I Know**

I know `Observable.subscribe` takes a passed in observer (which can be in different forms) and, via `toSubscribe.ts`, converts the observer to a `Subscriber` object. The new `Subscriber` object will have a `SafeSubscriber` instance in the `Subscriber.destination` property.

[This segment](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/06f1a25123997e0419a421aa949e8969bc5daeb1/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L21) from `Subscriber.ts` class is also relevant to the below question:

```
[rxSubscriberSymbol]() { return this; }
```

In the above code, the `rxSubscriberSymbol` `Symbol` property returns the class instance itself.

**My Question**

I get that `toSubscriber` must check if the observer is already a `Subscriber`. Well, I am not entirely sure *when* `toSubscribe` would be called with an observer that is *already* a `Subscriber`, but I guess there are times when that happens.

Why is it necessary to check *both* whether the observer is an instance of `Subscriber` *and* whether the `rxSubscriberSymbol` `Symbol` property exist? As far as I can tell, if an instance is an instance of `Subscriber` it *always* has the `rxSubscriberSymbol` `Symbol` property, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compose an observable by piping operators, like this:

```ts
const source = of(42);
const composed = source.pipe(
    map(value => (6 * 9) - value)
);
composed.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

there will an observable introduced for each operator.

Here, the caller is subscribing to the mapped observable and that mapped observable subscribes to the source.

When the caller subscribes, only the `next` handler is passed. That is, the caller doesn't pass a `Subscriber` instance - so `toSubscriber` is needed to create one. However, when the mapped observable subscribes to the source, it does so by passing the `map` operator's [`MapSubscriber`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.4.0/src/internal/operators/map.ts#L68-L91). You can see the call to `subscribe` made [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.4.0/src/internal/operators/map.ts#L58-L60).

`MapSubscriber` extends `Subscriber`, so there is no need for `toSubscriber` to create another; it can just return the `MapSubscriber` that it received.

The `rxSubscriberSymbol` is a `Symbol` that's used to identify `Subscriber` and `Subject` instances.

In version 5 of RxJS, this symbol was declared using `Symbol.for` - see [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/ef88ded3d671f48466ea3a42f9a2af656bd51d36/src/symbol/rxSubscriber.ts#L5-L6) - which meant that the same symbol would have been shared between different copies or versions of RxJS. And the symbol enabled interop between copies or versions - `Subscribers` from one copy wouldn't need to be wrapped by another.

In version 6, however, the symbol is declared using `Symbol` - see [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/8cc6491771fcbf44984a419b7f26ff442a5d58f5/src/internal/symbol/rxSubscriber.ts#L3-L5). Which means that it is essentially private, as each copy or version of RxJS will receive a unique symbol and it cannot perform an interop role.

`rxSubscriberSymbol` is used in `Subscriber` and in `Subject`, but now that it is a private symbol, it no longer serves a purpose and it seems, to me, to be unnecessary:

- Its use in `Subscriber` is not necessary, as the `instanceof Subscriber` check will identify `Subscriber` instances.
- And its use in `Subject` is unnecessary, as the `rxSubscriberSymbol` property in `Subject` - see [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/b24d3ea85d33b893e4c020fb4fa9f6fa4d05dc0b/src/internal/Subject.ts#L30-L32) - does nothing other than wrap the `Subject` in a `Subscriber` - which is what would happen in `toSubscriber` without the check.